# Django Based framework virtual host setup https on Apache

Tags: django, https, apache2, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am using a django based framework and have successfully figured Apache settings for http mode. Basically I have done the setting correctly on `<VirtualHost *:80> ... </VirtualHost>` and when I do, http://mysite.domain.com I get routed correctly to my site and the site pages and the skins get render correctly.

I have setup https://mysite.domain.com to work with shibboleth, shibboleth is working and when  use the https I get routed to login credential page via shibboleth server, and after successful login I get redirect to https://mysite.domain.com but site doesn't get rendered correctly and skins don't show up as same as http://mysite.domain.com.

Here is my Apache settings, I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin myname@mydomain.com
     DocumentRoot /code/vEnviornment/mysite
     ServerName mydomain.com
     #<LocationMatch "^(?!/admin)">
     #<LocationMatch "^(?!/m)">
     #    RewriteEngine on
     #    RewriteRule django.wsgi(.*)$ https://mydomain.com:443$1 [L,R=301]
     #</LocationMatch>
     SSLEngine on
     #your SSL keys
     #I have removed this wasn't comfortable putting SSL key info
     #Alias /admin/media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
     Alias /admin/media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
     WSGIScriptAlias /m/ /code/vEnviornment/mysite/django.wsgi
     <Directory "/">
     AuthType shibboleth
     ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
     Require valid-user
     </Directory>
     Alias /Shibboleth.sso /tmp
     #    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite/access_log common
     #    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite/access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is how I have hetup http:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin myname@mydomain.com
     DocumentRoot /code/vEnviornment/mysite
     ServerName mysite.mydomain.com

     #aliases to serve static media directly
     #will probably need adjustment
     Alias /m/ /code/vEnviornment/mysite/static/
     Alias /upfiles/ /code/vEnviornment/mysite/myframework/upfiles/
     <DirectoryMatch "/code/vEnviornment/mysite/myframework/skins/([^/]+)/media">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </DirectoryMatch>
     <Directory "/code/vEnviornment/mysite/myframework/upfiles">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
     #must be a distinct name within your apache configuration
     WSGIDaemonProcess mysite2
     WSGIProcessGroup mysite2
     WSGIScriptAlias / /code/vEnviornment/mysite/django.wsgi
     #make all admin stuff except media go through secure connection
     <LocationMatch "/admin(?!/media)">
     RewriteEngine on
         RewriteRule /admin(.*)$ https://128.101.35.71/admin$1 [L,R=301]
     </LocationMatch>
    # CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite/access_log common
    # ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite/access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite/error_log
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong here to render the site incorrectly via **https?**

Answer (score 0):

```
Alias /m/ /code/vEnviornment/mysite/static/
 Alias /upfiles/ /code/vEnviornment/mysite/myframework/upfiles/
```

These two lines are missing in https virual host

and

your WSGIScriptAlias should point to / not /m/